# Azure Check Web Application Gateway Already Exists

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-cli

Using the the Azure Az module is there a way to check if the 'Web Application Gateway' already exists?

Comment: Can you please share any code that you have tried?

Comment: Running the below will return json if the WAG exists. One of the JSON fields 'name' will have a value therefore I know it WAG exists. 
az network application-gateway show --name "inf-XXXXXX-001-prp-wag" --resource-group "network-rg"

Comment: If the WAG doesn't exist an error is returned...
PS /home/ian> az network application-gateway show --name "inf-xxxx-001-prp-wag" --resource-group "network-rg"   
(ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/inf-xxxx-001-prp-wag' under resource group 'network-rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/inf-xxxx-001-prp-wag' under resource group 'network-rg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed Azure Powershell [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-azapplicationgateway?view=azps-9.1.0#syntax):

```
$result =  Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "XX" -ResourceGroupName "YY" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($result -eq $null)
{
Write-Host("WAG Does Not Exists")
}else{
Write-Host("WAG  Exists")}
```

XX- Application gateway name,

YY- Name of the resource group

If Application gateway does not exists:

[image]

If Application Gateway exists:

[image]

You can also use below query and not use if else statements also:

[image]

In above you use `$?` to get if its true or false.
Try to follow above steps you will get expected output as I got.